# Are there infinitely many composite Euclid numbers of the second kind (Kummer numbers)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problem

$\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n p_i - 1$ is called Euclid number of the second kind (or Kummer number) , where $p_i$ is the i-th prime number.

It is not known whether there are infinitely many prime Kummer numbers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_number

Is it also unknown whether there are infinitely many composite Kummer numbers ?

Comment: I guess this is also unknown although it would be shocking if there were only finite many composites of this form.

Comment: I think so too.